# Removing units of measurement from a database (python)

Tags: python, pandas, database, string, units-of-measurement

[image]

I have a database that looks like the picture. I would like to remove all units of measurement. Some columns have writing on them is there any way I can do this?

```
3   390 kg/m3   1081 J/kgK  0.1 W/mK
4   420 kg/m3   1081 J/kgK  0.112 W/mK
5   600 kg/m3   1081 J/kgK  0.21 W/mK
6   2009.88 kg/m3   843.584 J/kgK   1.01233 W/mK
7   1674.2 kg/m3    933 J/kgK   0.685 W/mK
```

Comment: Ideally you should clean up everything before loading the values into a Pandas DataFrame. But you failed to say where the data came from... If you are directly passed a full DataFrame, the workaround would be to edit the relevant columns to remove the unit string and then convert them to a numeric dtype.

Answer (score 3):

You can clean the strings and leave only the digits. For example:

```
df['col'] =  df['col'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

For float values, you'll want to make sure the regular expression considers both before and after the decimal point and change the datatype:

```
df['col'] = df['col'].str.extract('(\d+\.\d+)').astype(float)
```